# Sort pandas dataframe by column specifying custom order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I got a csv that looks something like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
txt,txt,error,txt
txt,txt,new,txt
txt,txt,new,txt
txt,txt,error,txt
txt,txt,new,txt
txt,txt,fix,txt
```

Id like to change the order of the rows to this

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
txt,txt,new,txt
txt,txt,new,txt
txt,txt,new,txt
txt,txt,fix,txt
txt,txt,error,txt
txt,txt,error,txt
```

so the rows follows news -> change -> error in col3

So far tried different things with:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_dataframe = pd.read_csv(user_submitted_csv_file)
csv_dataframe = csv_dataframe.sort_values(by=['col3'])
```

But its not enough since it is not alphabetical nor ascending/descending.
also tried things like exstracting the rows -> deleting all rows -> adding back in correct order, but running into problems with that too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `pandas>=1.1.0` you can use the `key` argument of the [`.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html?highlight=sort_values#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) method to write a lambda function which defines the custom order you prefer.

To do it, you just need to define a custom dictionary with your desired order

```
custom_dict = {'new': 0, 'fix': 1, 'error': 2}
df.sort_values(by=['col3'], key=lambda x: x.map(custom_dict))
```

Comment: This answer is amazing. So much easier than using Categoricals. And it works on Index as well. And it can also ignore any values not in `custom_dict`.